# Convert multipage PDF to a single image

Tags: linux, image, bash, pdf, imagemagick

I have to convert a multipage PDF document to a .png image.

I try with ImageMagick, but I cannot achieve final result:

```
convert document.pdf document.png
```

or

```
convert -adjoin document.pdf document.png
```

This command create N images .png (where N=num of page of document):

```
document0.png
document1.png
.... 
document(N-1).png
```

I need, if possible with a single command, to obtain a single image.

Comment: you can merge the png files you've got with composite -blend 30 document0.png document1.png result.png

Comment: I don't need to merge.. if a.pdf have 2 pages (wxh), I want a single image wx2h. [w=width h=height]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Finally I find **THE** solution:

```
convert in.pdf -append out%d.png
```

Thanks to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick).

#### edit

As a plus, the opposite operation is:

```
convert *.png output.pdf
```

or if you have foo1.png, foo2.png..fooN.png

```
convert foo?.png output.pdf
```

Notice that does not work with foo01.png, foo02.png..foo0N.png

Comment: To fix text errors, add the "density" parameter to the command.

Comment: If anyone using RMagick and want to map above solution into RMagick then use this Doc: Magick Command Options and Their Equivalent Methods in RMagick - rmagick.github.io/optequiv.html

Comment: Only gives the errors, `convert-im6.q16: not authorized  convert-im6.q16: no images defined`

Answer (score 18):

`+append` will put images side by side, *i.e.* horizontally instead of  vertically (with `-append`)

```
convert in.pdf +append out%d.png
```

Comment: @Velthune `+1` for your Q+A when I was looking for almost the same!