# How to append pages of a pdf to a png in python with imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, magickwand

I'd like to convert a multipage PDF to a single PNG, which can be achieved via the CLI with `convert in.pdf -append out%d.png` per [Convert multipage PDF to a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605262/convert-multipage-pdf-to-a-single-image).

Can I achieve the same in Python without shelling out? I currently have:

```
with Image(filename=pdf_file_path, resolution=150) as img:
    img.background_color = Color("white")
    img.alpha_channel = 'remove'
    img.save(filename=pdf_file_path[:-3] + "png")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if [`MagickAppendImage`](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickAppendImages) has been ported to [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), but you should be able to leverage [`wand.image.Image.composite`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite).

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename=pdf_file_path) as pdf:
    page_index = 0
    height = pdf.height
    with Image(width=pdf.width,
               height=len(pdf.sequence)*height) as png:
        for page in pdf.sequence:
            png.composite(page, 0, page_index * height)
            page_index += 1
        png.save(filename=pdf_file_path[:-3] + "png")
```